# How to disable Sitecore login only (Sitecore Client - https://<domain>/sitecore/login)

Tags: paas

Is there a way to disable Sitecore Client for public but need to be available inside company network? I am having a domain 'mydomain'. I need https://mydomain/home (website) need to be accessible to public whereas https://mydomain/sitecore/login (client) should not. The later should work only inside company network. Please let me know.

#### Update from comments below:

This instance is hosted on Azure PaaS, not on premises.

Comment: Is this requirement for Content Management or Content Delivery? Normally Content Management does not require public access.

Comment: The simple answer here is to deploy a new App Instance and set the role to `Content Delivery` (Assuming >= 9.0) - You should not be delivering the public site on the same instance as the CM server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Sitecore environment on Azure, the App Service provides UX for this under Networking > Ip Restrictions, from there you can block all ip address and allow a specic ip address or a range of address. You can do this for your Contet Management environment.

See this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990318/how-to-restrict-ip-addresses-with-an-azure-app-service-web-app) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Currently our CM environment is hosted on Azure. The requirement is we need to make all CM Sites as public but we do not want Sitecore client to be available public. How I can do it there?

Comment: @ManideepYechuri I'd question the requirement to make the CM site public? Why is this necessary - Can you provide more context?

Comment: @sitecorium, Our client is using a chrome extension (Veeva Web2PDF) for converting entire site into pdfs (in order to reduce manual effort for their content approvals) but that extension works only for public sites. As our CM environment is not public but client is insisting upon the usage of that extension, we are going to make CM Public.

Answer (score 0):

Same case we have in one of our implementation where we are using third party tool which created PDF of Journeys which we have in website. We resolved that in below fashion hope same will help you.

1. First you need to get the IP(Public) address of the extension.
2. Go to CM role of your Azure app.
3. Then go to Networking under that go to Access Restrictions.
4. Then whitelist the IP which you got from team.

Above resolved our issue and we haven't messed anything for CM website and this also allowed us CM website not make Public.

Hope this will solve your issue